# How to generate derivative list with frequencies

Tags: c++, random, text, statistics, generator

I have some C++ code that picks a random item from a list. I need it to weight that randomness so that an item at place "n" has a chance equal to x/n where "x" is the chance that item one in the list will be selected. My current code is like this:

```
srand(time(NULL));
string a[≈9000] = {"String#1", "String#2", . . ., "String #≈9000"};
int value = rand() % ≈9000;
cout << a[value]
```

Note that the number notated as "≈9000" is a precise integer obscured for confidentiality. Variable names may be changed.

How can I weight it? I've come up with an equivalent formula

```
List B[≈9000] = "Item 'n' of 'a' times ≈9000 ÷ n"
```

Though you might notice that that isn't accurate CPP notation. Do y'all have any ideas how I can implement this?

Comment: In an old old program called Dragonfire (used for table top RPGs), a table could have weighted entries.  A **Sword +1** maybe has a weight of 10, while a **Sword +2** has a weight of 3.  The random number is generated from 1 to the sum of the weights, then walks through the items accumulating weights to find which particular item was chosen from its range-span.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm trying to do. The only difference is I'm trying to automate the weight with a formula.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

[image: sum from 0 to N-1 of 0.05/n != 1]

You need somehow to allow a variation on your conditions to have a proper distribution.